# Scheduling execution of blocks in Objective C

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm creating an application in objective C where I have two threads:

1. The main thread, which is woken up from sleep and is called into asynchronously by a module above it
2. The callback block(thread) whose execution is asynchronous and is dependent on an external module "M" sending a notification.

On my main thread, I want to wait for the callback to come in before I start doing my tasks. So, I tried using `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_wait(FOREVER)` on the main thread while calling into `dispatch_group_leave` on the callback thread. This ensured that when the main thread is the first to execute, things happen as they are supposed to, i.e the main thread waits for the callback to come in and unblock it before performing its tasks.

However, I'm seeing a race condition where the callback block gets called first sometimes and is stuck on `dispatch_group_leave` (since at this point the main thread has not called into `dispatch_group_enter`.

Is there a different GCD construct I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Why so complex? In GCD you don't typically think in terms of threads.  They are abstracted below queues.  You would typically create a queue for your "main thread" (That is not a great term to use since "main thread" has a specific meaning in iOS, so I will call it WorkQueue.  If of course, you are talking about blocking The Main Thread, then that is a very bad idea).  When the callback code is executed it can simply dispatch the required task onto WorkQueue. GCD will find an appropriate thread to execute the work. There is no reason for this task to "sleep"; It is either executing or not.

Answer (score 0):

The “main thread” is a thread which handles UI, system events, notifications, etc. We never block that thread. Blocking it results in a horrible UX where the app will appear to freeze and your app may even be terminated by the “watch dog” process, which kills apps that it thinks are frozen. In some cases, the app will deadlock.

So, if you really mean “main thread”, then the answer is that you would never “wait” on that thread (or otherwise block it). The pattern is to have your background thread do what it needs, and then dispatch model/UI updates back to the main thread with GCD (or submit your notification and let the main thread process it).

If you want a UX where the user is not allowed to interact with the UI while this background process is underway, you would present something in your UI that makes that clear. A common pattern is a dimming/blurring view that covers the whole view, often with a [`UIActivityIndicatorView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview) (i.e., a spinner), and when the task dispatched to the background queue is done (or have the notification handler do that), you’d then remove that dimming/blurred view and the spinner and update the UI accordingly.

But you never block the main thread by waiting.